# Android SimpleCursorTreeAdapter Hanging

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter in some code I'm writing for learning purposes.  What is happening is that when I click on a parent it expands and shows the children, but then I can't do anything more.  I walked the code using the debugger and fould that I am stuck in a never ending loop inside looper.loop.  I have commented out all of the stuff that does actual working in the snippet below but it still hangs.  With the snippet below, I would expect that clicking on a second parent would cause it to expand (as indicated by the arrow changing).
I left the old stuff in the code (but commented out) to show what I was trying to do.

I would really appreciate any advice or suggestions.

```
    private void showEvents(final Cursor cursor) {

    ExpandableListView lv1 = this.getExpandableListView();



    SimpleCursorTreeAdapter  adapter = new SimpleCursorTreeAdapter (this, cursor, R.layout.simplerow, FROM, TO, 
            R.layout.childrow, FROMCHILD, TOCHILD) {
        //@Override
        //public void setViewText(TextView v, String text) {
        //  super.setViewText(v, convText(v, text, cursor));
        //}

        @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor parentCursor) {

            int groupPos = parentCursor.getPosition(); 
              Log.d("TEST", "getChildrenCursor() for groupPos " + groupPos); 

            String sql = "select f._id, f.NAME as ASSETCLASS, "
                    + "f.value as AMOUNT, "
                    + "0 as PERCENTAGE, "
                    + "0 as TARGET "
                    + "from funds f "
                    + "where f.asset_class = " + parentCursor.getInt(0) + ";";

            sql = "select f._id, f.NAME as FUNDNAME, "
                    + "f.value as AMOUNT_OWNED "
                    + "from funds f "
                    + "where 1  = 1;";



            Log.d("TEST", sql);

            //SQLiteDatabase db = pfdata.getReadableDatabase();

            //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
            //startManagingCursor(cursor);
            //return cursor;

            //Log.d("TEST", Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));
            //return cursor;
            return null;
        }

    };

    // Log.d("TEST", Integer.toString(adapter.getCount()));

    lv1.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

I tried the suggestion but I didn't see any change in the behavior.  Here is what I have currently:

```
    private void showEvents(final Cursor cursor) {

    ExpandableListView lv1 = this.getExpandableListView();


    MyExpandableListAdapter mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(cursor, this, 
            R.layout.simplerow, R.layout.childrow, 
               FROM, TO, 
               FROMCHILD, TOCHILD); 
        lv1.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
       }

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter { 


public MyExpandableListAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context, 
        int groupLayout, int childLayout, String[] groupFrom, 
        int[] groupTo, String[] childrenFrom, int[] childrenTo) { 
    super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, 
            childLayout, childrenFrom, childrenTo); 
} 

@Override 
protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor parentCursor) { 

    String sql = "select f._id, f.NAME as ASSETCLASS, "
            + "f.value as AMOUNT, "
            + "0 as PERCENTAGE, "
            + "0 as TARGET "
            + "from funds f "
            + "where f.asset_class = " + parentCursor.getInt(0) + ";";

    Log.d("TEST", sql);

    return null;        
}
```

I tried with actually running the query and returning the cursor, but it didn't make a difference so I tried to go back to the basics.
If anyone has any ideas on what is going on, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue is becasue you are overriding `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` instead of extending it.  When you do that, you need to re-create all the methods it uses to work the list (which you haven't done).

You have two choices:  add in all the missing methods or create a new class that extends `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` and use that as your adapter.  The last (IMO) is far easier than the first.  You simply override the methods you need.

An example from one of my projects follows.

```
mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(mGroupsCursor, getActivity(),
       R.layout.rowlayout_expgroup, R.layout.rowlayout_itemlist_exp,
       new String[] { "_id" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
       new String[] { GroceryDB.ITEM_NAME, GroceryDB.LISTITEM_QTY,
               GroceryDB.ITEM_UNIT }, new int[] { R.id.ListItem1,
               R.id.ListItem3, R.id.ListItem2 });
lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {
    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context,
            int groupLayout, int childLayout, String[] groupFrom,
            int[] groupTo, String[] childrenFrom, int[] childrenTo) {
        super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,
                childLayout, childrenFrom, childrenTo);
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
        Cursor childCursor = mDbHelper.fetchChildren(GroceryListMain.group,
                groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")),
                ListFragment_ShopList.listId);
        getActivity().startManagingCursor(childCursor);
        childCursor.moveToFirst();
        return childCursor;
    }

    protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor,
            boolean isLastChild) {
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListItem1);
        TextView qty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListItem3);
        TextView unit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListItem2);
        TextView cost = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListItem4);

        name.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        qty.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        unit.setText(cursor.getString(4));
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        Double hold = Double.valueOf(cursor.getString(3));
        Double qtyhold = Double.valueOf(cursor.getString(1));
        Double total = hold * qtyhold;
        cost.setText("$" + df.format(total));
    }
}
```